# NSCalendarUnit.Type doesnt have a member named CalendarUnitWeekDay

Tags: nscalendar, swift2

```
let currentDayOfWeek = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.CalendarUnitWeekday, fromDate: NSDate())
```

In this place I get an error:

> `NSCalendarUnit.Type` doesnt have a member named `CalendarUnitWeekDay`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't, it does have `Weekday`, which can be used in this way:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let component = calendar.component(.Weekday, fromDate:NSDate())
```